# Creating a Python dictionary from two columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, data-analysis

Trying hard to create a dictionary by comparing values and to add greater values more than 90 into a new dictionary. I have an actual data set working on with pandas but to simplify, i will try to explain with lists

```
list_names = ['annie','betty', 'charlie','debie', 'elf', 'frank', 'goe', 'hayri']
list_ages = [19,23,44,31,55,65,15,40]
```

The ages are corresponding to each name in the list and the target is to create a key:value pair that contains values only older than 30.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: `dict(zip(list_names, list_ages))` or to filter, `{k: v for k,v in zip(list_names, list_ages) if v >30}`

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
list_names = ['annie','betty', 'charlie','debie', 'elf', 'frank', 'goe', 'hayri'] 
list_ages = [19,23,44,31,55,65,15,40]

{name: age for name, age in zip(list_names,list_ages) if age>30}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try taking example from this code:
list_names = name((k, v) for k, v in list_names.items() if v > 30)